# How to get NTLM version authentication with select statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, authentication, logins

From my using SSMS I connect to SQL Server 2019. I would like to know what authentication is my current session connection using. I executed SQL:

```
select
    auth_scheme
from
    sys.dm_exec_connections
where
    session_id = @@spid
;
```

Output is: NTLM

How can I know if this is NTML v1 or NTLM v2. Is there select I can write?

Regards

Comment: If you can't get it from SQL, you might have to set up auditing at the OS level to find out. See https://dirteam.com/sander/2022/06/15/howto-detect-ntlmv1-authentication/

Comment: NTLMv1 is completely disabled these days on a new-build Active Directory